# Does GNU runs exclusively in linux user space?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, gnu

I understand that Android runs in user space (and then, due to the Linux exception on the GPL for user space, does not have to comply with the GPL).

I am wondering (for no particular reason) if GNU (as used in Linux distributions) is actually also running only in user space?

Answer (score 4):

On Linux systems, the only code that ever runs *not* in user space is kernel code, or code injected into the kernel (*e.g.* using BPF). The various GNU programs run in user space.

(There is a subtle distinction here, which isn’t directly relevant to the question but worth pointing out anyway — *processes* run in both user and kernel space: kernel requests handled on behalf of a user-space program are considered as running in the calling process; but they don’t run involve code provided by the calling program, which is why the GPL stops at the kernel boundary.)

Answer (score 1):

Grub is a GNU project, and it doesn't run in user space, so if you wanted to win a bet with this question, you could use this technicality.

Answer (score 0):

To complete @StephenKitt's answer, and simplifying, [Linux is the kernel while GNU is the programs that make up the whole OS](https://www.gnu.org/gnu/linux-and-gnu.en.html). So yes, GNU software runs in user space.

> There really is a Linux, and these people are using it, but it is just a part of the system they use. Linux is the kernel: the program in the system that allocates the machine's resources to the other programs that you run. The kernel is an essential part of an operating system, but useless by itself; it can only function in the context of a complete operating system. Linux is normally used in combination with the GNU operating system: the whole system is basically GNU with Linux added, or GNU/Linux. All the so-called “Linux” distributions are really distributions of GNU/Linux.

Comment: That's the way the FSF likes to put it. In reality, they didn't manage to make their own kernel fly and tried to marry the linux kernel. But linux likes to be unbound, and I am quite sure that most linux systems today run without any line of GNU code, just because they are embedded systems that can't comply to GPLv3 without lots of pain. So the phrase *normally used in combination* is just true for servers and desktops, which is just a fraction of the linux world. Thus, *linux is the kernel, while GNU can be part of the programs that make up the whole OS*.